# Detect Dialog Window creation ex. "File Download"

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, winforms

How do i detect when a window appears?  ex. "File Download" window

What i have tried:

1. delaying the program until the "page" loads

   1. this does not work, it presses button long time after dialog appears
   2. so the dialog is not created when the page is completed
   3. this worked for regular HTML pages
   4. there is also Ajax called before the page loads
2. delaying the program for a set time

   1. does not work, the window is a very random time to appear
   2. sometimes its almost instant, other times its over 10 seconds

What i Can't do: use webclient, i can't get it to authenticate

Summary:
  I need a way to hold up the code until the dialog Window appears.

```
string url = "http:/.....(not a pdf, but it returns one

webBrowser1.Navigate(url);  

//does not wait for the "page" to load, waits for regular url
//  await PageLoad(10);      

//waits... sometimes the window isn't ready yet
//  await Task.Delay(10000);  
{
  //press the save button
  IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download");
  hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "&Save");  
  uint message = 0xf5;
  SendMessage(hwnd, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

  //lets me see when the code has skipped waiting
  richTextBox2.AppendText(hwnd + " " + "\n");  //for debug only
}
```

Comment: A simple workaround might be to use `Thread.Sleep`, or similar.

Comment: i have tried await Task.Delay, but i don't know how long to wait for the window to show up... a few seconds to feels like forever is how long it takes the dialog window to show up.    the PageLoad call waits for the webbrowserreadystate to be complete, or waits 10 seconds.  the dialog window that pops up is not tied to that at all.  it appears that the webbrowser is ready before it pops up dialog windows

Comment: Why don't you try checking the `WebBrowserReadyState` for `Complete`?  You could check it, say, every 30 milliseconds until it's true.

Comment: webBrowserReadyState.Complete is not working for me also, i have kept looking at my problem, there is Ajax in the page i am going to, so the page completes extremely fast, then the Ajax starts, and takes a long time to load